# Why is showing $LHS - RHS \geq 0$ enough to prove convexity of a function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convexity-inequality

I understand the definition of a convex function to be the following:

$$ \alpha f(x) + (1 - \alpha) f(y) \geq f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y)$$

Intuitively, this means that any point on a line connecting some $x$ and $y$ on the function should exist above a corresponding point on the function. What is confusing me is that for some proofs, all that is shown is that the right hand subtracted from the left hand is greater than or equal to zero. It makes sense because one thing minus another greater than zero implies the first thing must be greater than the second. I guess what confuses me is that I cant understand when it would be the case that subtracting right from left wouldn't produce some difference that is greater than/equal to zero. Sorry if this question is poorly worded. I will try to clarify what I mean if anybody asks.

Comment: Are you asking why $A \ge B$ is equivalent to $A - B \ge 0$?

Comment: @MartinR No. I understand why that is the case. What confuses me is that it seems like you could take any function for $f$ in this inequality and subtract right from left and claim it is convex. I guess what I am curious to see is a case where this is used to show that some function is not convex. Does that make sense?

Comment: @dminzi Can you write this down? Maybe even for a concrete example for a non-convex function $f$?

Comment: But $\alpha f(x) + (1 - \alpha) f(y) - f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) \ge 0$ does not hold for any function...

Comment: It is perhaps more instructive to consider what convexity means in terms of sets. The point $\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y $ is on the line joining $x,y$ for various $\alpha$ but only in the segment $[x,y]$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$. The definition in the question is just saying the the epigraph of $f$ (the points on & above the graph) is convex.

Comment: @supinf Thank you! I tried it for $\sqrt{x}$ and it became pretty clear. Sorry for such a silly question. It's been a while since I've been in a class like this one, so I'm a bit rusty.